# Child UK Visa for baby born in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I am in UK on tier 2 visa.We have our baby born here in London last month. 
I have applied for Indian Citizenship certificate and also for the Indian Passport for the child.

Just want to know what else is required for the baby, if we plan to return to India? We do not intend to come back to UK, so probably no dependent visa required for him? Also, hope this would not impact any future visa processing for my child.

Thank you.
Regards
Saloni